Copying all items in vector of class obj. between min and max values (by field) to another vector and then removing them
So I'm new to cpp, and I have a program that finds min and max values in vector of class objects ( by field ) and I need to move all the items in between them into another vector and then remove them from the original vector. I cant wrap my head around it, how do I iterate through the vector with an iterator and check the condition (it > minVal && it < maxVal).
Here's the class that I wrote:
class Ball {
private:
    int size;
    std::string color;

public:
    Ball() :size(0), color("") {};
    Ball(int size, std::string color) : size(size), color(color) {}
    int get_size() { return size; }
    std::string get_color() { return color; }

    //перегрузка операторів для зручності роботи 
    bool operator<(const Ball& other) { return size < other.size; }  
    bool operator>(const Ball& other) { return size > other.size; }  
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Ball& ball) { //дружня ф-ція перегрузки оператора "<<" для виводу всіх полів
        os <<  ball.size << "\\" << ball.color;
        return os;
    }
};

I have a func that outputs two class objects: minBall, and maxBall (by size field).
I tried to use std::find_if() and wrote a basic comparator for it:
bool comparator_for_ext(Ball& a, Ball& minBall, Ball& maxBall) {
    return a < maxBall && a > minBall;
}

How what do I pass into compatator_for_ext() as "a"
 std::find_if(balls.begin(), balls.end(), comparator_for_ext(what to pass here, minBall, maxBall))

std::copy_if with a back inserter for the copying. std::remove_if for removing them.

@Garry Let's assume that the first vector contains objects with sizes { 5, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1 } then what elements should be moved in the second vector?

Unrelated: in your top paragraph, you talk about && but your comparator uses ||. Assuming minBall <= maxBall, the condition a < maxBall || a > minBall will always evaluate to true.

@VladfromMoscow I think copy all the items from the first occurance of the max one

@Garry That is do you mean that for the range I showed the first vector will have the first element and the last element { 5, 1 } and the second vector will have all other elements that is { 5, 3, 1, 4, 2 }?

@VladfromMoscow I meant not only from first occurance of max element, but - from first occurance of the min element to first occurance of the max element, vice versa.

@Garry Can it be that you actually mean first occurrence of the minimal element and the LAST occurrence of the maximum element and vice versa? Show result vectors for the range I provided in my first comment.

@VladfromMoscow So in the given case the first vector will have objects with sizes { 5, 1, 4, 2, 1} and the extracted one will have { 5, 3}

If you need to move elements in the range from the first minimum element to the first maximum element or vice versa from one vector to another vector then neither std::find_if or std::remove_if algorithm you need.
What you need are three algorithms: std::min_element, std::max_element and std::minmax.
Here is a demonstration program for vectors of the type std::vector<int> You can use the approach for vectors of objects of your type.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 5, 5, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1 };
    std::vector<int> v2;

    for (const auto &item : v1)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    auto min = std::min_element( std::begin( v1 ), std::end( v1 ) );
    auto max = std::max_element( std::begin( v1 ), std::end( v1 ) );

    if ( min != max )
    {
        auto range = std::minmax( min, max );

        v2.assign( std::next( range.first ), range.second );

        v1.erase( std::next( range.first ), range.second );
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    for (const auto &item : v1)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (const auto &item : v2)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

The program output is
5 5 3 1 4 2 1

5 1 4 2 1
5 3

I have updated my answer with a demonstration program for objects of your class.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

class Ball
{
private:
    unsigned int size;
    std::string color;

public:
    Ball() : Ball( 0, "" ) { }
    Ball( unsigned int size, const std::string &color ) : size( size ), color( color ) {}
    unsigned int get_size() const { return size; }
    std::string get_color() const { return color; }

    //перегрузка операторів для зручності роботи 
    bool operator <( const Ball &other ) const { return size < other.size; }
    bool operator >( const Ball &other ) const { return size > other.size; }

    //дружня ф-ція перегрузки оператора "<<" для виводу всіх полів
    friend std::ostream &operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Ball &ball )
    {
        os << ball.size << "\\" << ball.color;
        return os;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<Ball> v1 =
    {
        { 5, "red" }, { 5, "green" }, {3, "blue" },
        { 1, "red" }, { 4, "green" }, { 2, "blue" }, { 1, "red"}
    };

    std::vector<Ball> v2;

    for (const auto &item : v1)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    auto min = std::min_element( std::begin( v1 ), std::end( v1 ) );
    auto max = std::max_element( std::begin( v1 ), std::end( v1 ) );

    if ( min != max )
    {
        auto range = std::minmax( min, max );

        v2.assign( std::next( range.first ), range.second );

        v1.erase( std::next( range.first ), range.second );
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    for (const auto &item : v1)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (const auto &item : v2)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

The program output is
5\red 5\green 3\blue 1\red 4\green 2\blue 1\red

5\red 1\red 4\green 2\blue 1\red
5\green 3\blue


Thanks! But how do I adapt it for a vector of class objects? It throws an error on me saying: no instance of function template matches the argument list             argument types are: (const Ball)
at
`void extractBalls(std::vector& balls, Ball minBall, Ball maxBall, std::vector& extracted) {
auto range = std::minmax(minBall, maxBall);
extracted.assign(std::nextstd::iterator(range.first), range.second);
}
`

@Garry For starters use next( ... )  as written in my demonstration program instead of nextstd::terator( ... )

Still didn't work for me. Std::minmax returns std::pair do i need to cast my minBall\maxBall to iterators?

@Garry Of course minBall and maxBall shall be iterators. All is showed in my demonstration program.

find_if accepts a unary predicate (comparator). Notice you're passing the predicate itself to find_if, not calling it. One way you can do this is to create a new function that will call comparator_for_ext with the needed values.
auto ball_it = std::find_if(balls.begin(), balls.end(), [=](const Ball& a){ return comparator_for_ext(a, minBall, maxBall); });

Another way would be to define a callable class which you can construct with the minBall and maxBall values and pass as predicate to find_if
class BallInRange {
private:
    const Ball& minBall;
    const Ball& maxBall;
public:
    BallInRange(const Ball& min, const Ball& max) : minBall(min), maxBall(max) {}

    bool operator()(const Ball& a) const {
        return a < maxBall && a > minBall;
    }
};

Then the call to find_if would look like this
BallInRange ball_predicate(minBall,maxBall);
auto ball_it = std::find_if(balls.begin(), balls.end(), ball_predicate);

Unrelated - comparator_for_ext as you wrote it would evaluate as true for every ball.

Without answering my comment to the question by the author your answer does not make sense.

@Vlad Keel so I tried your answer with lambda expression and it throws an error: qualifiers dropped in binding reference of type to initializer of type

@Garry drop the "const" qualifier from the lambda, or better yet add it to your comparator_for_ext arguments
